# Macro imports text file into multiple worksheets, I just want it all to import into one

Tags: vba, excel

... and have "***" between each file

here's what I have so far:

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim x As Integer
Dim wkbAll As Workbook
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim sDelimiter As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sDelimiter = "|"

FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
  (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No Files were selected"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If

x = 1
Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
wkbTemp.Close (False)
wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
  Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
  Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
  Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
  Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
x = x + 1

While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    With wkbAll
        wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.count)
        .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
          Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
          TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
          ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
          Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
          Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
          Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
    End With
    x = x + 1
Wend

ExitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wkbAll = Nothing
Set wkbTemp = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

I was able to copy this from another website but I haven't been able to find a code that imports multiple into one and adds a spacer between each file.

Comment: Do you undertand how your code works? Aside from the fact that this site is is for actual questions, not "write my code for me", you shouldn't just run a macro that you don't understand from somewhere on the internet. Tell us what you tried to do to refine the code for your purposes, and explain how that failed.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this. I don't usually do file imports....

Comment: Don't run code if you can't read code. It is bad practice that could run you into trouble - either through malicious code, or because something critical fails in a way that you are unable to fix.

Comment: I know how to read a majority of the code, it's just the importing that gets me.

Comment: `wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.count)`
This part of the code is doing what it is supposed to do. Instead You need to copy the range in each sheet and paste it into the other sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was pretty much complete. I added an error handler to make sure that you had a target worksheet on the active workbook along with some minor modifications that added the series of asterisks after each imported TXT block.

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
    Dim FilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim wsTXT As Worksheet, wkbAll As Workbook, wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String

    On Error GoTo Missing_TXT_Ws
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsTXT = wkbAll.Worksheets("TXT_All")

    'uncomment the next line if you want to start fresh
    'wsTXT.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.ClearContents

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sDelimiter = Chr(124)   'e.g. "|"

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    For x = LBound(FilesToOpen) To UBound(FilesToOpen)
        'Debug.Print FilesToOpen(x)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x), ReadOnly:=True)
        With wkbTemp.Sheets(1)
            .Columns(1).TextToColumns _
                  Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                  DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                  Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
                  Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
                  Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
            .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy _
              Destination:=wsTXT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            wsTXT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = String(32, Chr(42))
        End With
        wkbTemp.Close False
    Next x

    With wsTXT
        If Not CBool(Application.CountA(.Rows(1))) Then .Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    GoTo ExitHandler

Missing_TXT_Ws:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        With wkbAll
            .Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            .Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "TXT_All"
        End With
        Resume
    End If
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wsTXT = Nothing
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to change it so that there are only 3 asterisks?

Comment: An asterisk is ASCII character 42. The line that puts that in is `String(32, Chr(42))`. Just change 32 to 3 and you should be all set.

Comment: YES! I owe you big time!